# ASP.NET Core installing package

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, c#-6.0, c#-7.0

I am new to ASP.NET Core and I am facing with this stubborn problem. When I try to download the Entity Framework Core for SqlServer, it return the error like the picture posted.  I appreciate your help really much [My error when trying to download Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk4b6.png)

I tried repair the Visual Studio but nothing change. Before this happen, I got so many errors of nuspec that I have to restore it but it led to this error.

Comment: Have you tried installing other version of package?

Comment: I tried but the version I was able to install is 3.0.0, and I am using .NET 7.0. Is that gonna compatible with each other ?

Comment: can you please add .csproj file? At least the section with packages?

Comment: Try other methods of installing. For example installing it by nuget console:                              https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/

Answer (score 0):

Please do post the contents of your project file.

Try installing another version of the "Entity Framework Core SqlServer" package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of Entity framework. Then try installing older one.otherwise try more latest one. problem is not in visual studio. problem is dependencies of your project. EntityFramework Version is incompatible with your current .NET Version.that's problem as I see.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a magical way that I installed the pre-release version with .Net 8.0. And now it is working properly. I really appreciate every supports of yours. Thank you all !